# In the measurable space $(\Omega ,{\rm B})$, show ${\rm A} \in {\rm B}$ iff ${1_{\rm A}} \in {\rm B}$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I'm little confused about how to show ${1_{\rm A}} \in {\rm B}$ $\Rightarrow $${1_{\rm A}} \in {\rm B}$.

I think the second implication is simple:

${\rm A} \in {\rm B}$ $\Leftarrow $ ${1_{\rm A}} \in {\rm B}$

If ${1_{\rm A}} \in {\rm B}$, so ${\rm A} = 1_{\rm A}^{ - 1}\{ 1\}  \in {\rm B}$.

Comment: FWIW, the assertion that $$1_{\rm A} \in {\rm B}$$ is absurd since $\rm B$ is a collection of events and $1_{\rm A}$ is not an event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $A\in B$. To show $1_A\in B$ we need to show that $1_A^{-1}((a,\infty))\in B$ for all $a\in\Bbb R$. To do this, consider separately the cases $a<0$, $0\le a< 1$, and $a\ge 1$.

Comment: thank you! I understood